# jQuery: inserting DOM elements and attaching events

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a JQuery plugin and I am having a problem when creating DOM elements and attaching a click event to them.  My code for creating the DOM elements is shown below:

```
    return this.each(function () {
        $this = $(this);

        $("<div class=\"" + settings.headingClass + "\">" + $this.attr("title") + "</div>").insertBefore($this).click(function () {
            alert($this.attr("title"));
        });
    });
```

The values of `$this.attr("title")` are correct when rendered on the page and the click event fires on each element however, the alert box always displays the value of `$this.attr("title")` for the last element.

Example:

My plugin is being applied to 3 elements with titles "Title1", "Title2" and "Title3".  The generated HTML displays these titles correctly but the alert box only displays "Title3" no matter what title element I click on.

Any ideas?

**Extra Information**

I'm providing some extra information to help with this.  I'm creating a basic expander plugin to try and get to grips with JQuery plugin development.

Example of HTML element:

```
<div class="MyExpander" title="Title1">
    This is my expanders content
</div>
```

JS to create JQuery expander:

```
$(".QuizExpander").expander({
    "headingClass": "ExpanderHeading"
});
```

Plugin code so far:

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.expander = function (options) {
    var settings = {
        "headingClass": "",
    };

    if (options) {
        $.extend(settings, options);
    }

    return this.each(function () {
        $this = $(this);

        $("<div class=\"" + settings.headingClass + "\">" + $this.attr("title") + "</div>").insertBefore($this).click(function () {
            alert($this.attr("title"));
        });
    });
};
```

})(jQuery);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: The reason you get this behavior is forgetting to use `var` with function-local variables. Failing to use `var` creates global variables instead.

Consequently, your `$this` in the `click()` function was the global one, not the one you defined in `each()`.

---

**Original answer:** There are some obvious issues with your code, but in principle it should work (at least it does for me, see http://jsfiddle.net/CpeNM/).

Your code sample is either missing the relevant part, or I misunderstood the question. Anyway - here is what I think is wrong with your code in general:

```
return this.each(function () {
  // ALWAYS!!! use the var keyword for local variables (or global ones will be created)
  var $this = $(this);
  // use the jQuery functions to modify new DOM objects, avoid string-building
  var $div  = $("<div>").addClass(settings.headingClass).attr("title", $this.attr("title"));

  $div.insertBefore($this).click(function () {
    // theoretically you could use 'alert($(this).text());' here
    alert($this.attr("title"));
  });
});​
```

Comment: The absence of var on the $this variable caused the problem.  So it was a problem with the global variable.  Makes sense!

Comment: @Jason: Regarding the "avoid string building" part: Unless you are in a very high-demand loop that blocks the UI noticeably, your should prefer DOM methods (and their jQuery wrappers) to build DOM objects. Concatenating complex HTML from strings just breaks too easily. And in jQuery, it's even far uglier than the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

In every walk-trough of `this.each()`, `$this` gets overridden. So you have to say something like this (if the following `this` is a jQuery object, else you'll have to wrap a `$()` around it):

```
return this.before(
  $('<div class="' + settings.headingClass + '">' + this.attr("title") + '</div>')
  .click(function() {
     alert(this.attr("title"));
  });
});
```

Comment: @elektronik: This would work but does not explain why the OP is seeing the issue in the first place. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
return this.each(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    $("div", $(this)).live('click', function () {
        alert($this.attr("title"));
    });

    $("<div class=\"" + settings.headingClass + "\">" + $this.attr("title") + "</div>").insertBefore($this);
});
```

Basically, I'm splitting it up into two calls. live() doesn't require the DOM element to exist for the event to apply.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: that's not the problem, because $this gets overridden in every walk-through of this.each(). (see my answer)